# Thread-safe atomic operations in gcc

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, atomic

In a program I work on, I have a lot of code as follows:

```
pthread_mutex_lock( &frame->mutex );
frame->variable = variable;
pthread_mutex_unlock( &frame->mutex );
```

This is clearly a waste of CPU cycles if the middle instruction can just be replaced with an atomic store.  I know that gcc is quite capable of this, but I haven't been able to find much documentation on such simple thread-safe atomic operations.  How would I replace this set of code with an atomic operation?

(I know that simple stores should theoretically be atomic, but I don't want to have to hope that the optimizer isn't screwing up their atomic-ness at some point in the process.)

Clarification: I do not need them to be strictly atomic; these variables are solely used for thread synchronization.  That is, Thread B reads the value, checks if its correct, and if its not correct, it sleeps.  So even if Thread A updates the value and Thread B doesn't realize its updated, that isn't a problem, since that just means Thread B sleeps when it didn't really need to, and when it wakes up, the value will be correct.

Comment: Since kernel 2.6, the cost of a mutex is almost nothing when the mutex is free. Anyway, "__sync_lock_test_and_set" (since gcc 4.1) should do the trick, this is not the only function that could be used in this case.

Comment: __atomic_store or __atomic_store_n seems more appropriate btw.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there functions for performing atomic operations in the standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302674/are-there-functions-for-performing-atomic-operations-in-the-standard-library)

Answer (score 16):

You could check the gcc documentation. For the current gcc version (4.3.2) it would be chapter 5.47 [Built-in functions for atomic memory access](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html) - for other gcc versions please check your docs. It should be in chapter 5- Extensions to the C Language Family.

Incidentally, the C compiler makes absolutely no guarantee as to simple store operations being atomic. You cannot rely on that assumption. In order for a machine opcode to be executed atomically, it needs the LOCK prefix.

Comment: Moreover, this built-in functions for atomic memory access are also supported by ICC (in case you intend to be compiler portable).
For GCC, I think atomic functions are supported since 4.1 so be sure to have some #ifdef to ensure gcc or icc version!

Comment: So in case of concurrent access, __sync_add_and_fetch is not reliable ? and we have to use lock addx directly with assembly inlining ?

Answer (score 16):

Up to a certain point, atomic operations in C were provided straight from the kernel sources via the atomic.h header.

However, having kernel headers being used directly in user-space code is a very bad practice, so the atomic.h header file was removed some time ago. Instead we ca now make use of the "GCC Atomic Builtins" which are a far better and more reliable approach.

There is a [very good explanation provided by Tudor Golubenco on his blog](http://golubenco.org/?p=7). He even provides a drop-in replacement for the initial atomic.h file, in case you have some code that needs it.

Unfortunately I'm new to stackoverflow, so I can only use one link in my comments, so check Tudor's post and get enlightened.

Answer (score 4):

On x86 and most other architectures, aligned 4-byte reads and writes are always atomic.  The optimizer may skip/reorder reads and writes within a single thread, though.

What you want to do is inform the compiler that other threads may have touched this memory location.  (A side effect of `pthread_mutex_lock` is telling the compiler that other threads may have touched any part of memory.)  You may see `volatile` recommended, but this not in the C specification, and GCC doesn't interpret `volatile` that way.

```
asm("" : "=m" (variable));
frame->variable = variable;
```

is a GCC-specific mechanism to say that "`variable` has been written to, reload it".

Comment: Beyond that, the processor's cache may hide or reorder reads and writes with respect to other processors... so a memory fence is needed.  pthread_mutex_lock provides this, but it is very architecture-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't prefix MOV instructions with LOCK; this is allowed only for RMW operations.  But if he *does* use a simple store, he might also need a memory barrier, which is implicit with mutex, as well as with instructions that allow LOCK.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see, you're using gnu platform for development, so it's safe to say that glic provides a datatype int ranged with atomic capabilities, `'sig_atomic_t'` . So this approach can assure you atomic operations at kernel levels. not gcc levels.

Comment: `sig_atomic_t` is only atomic with respect to signals.  It is *not* thread-safe.